# How to debug lost events posted from non-GUI thread in Qt?

Tags: qt, events, multithreading, gstreamer

As the subject says, I'm posting events from non-GUI thread (some GStreamer thread, to be precise). Code looks like this:

```
GstBusSyncReply on_bus_message(GstBus* bus, GstMessage* message, gpointer data)
{
    bool ret = QMetaObject::invokeMethod(static_cast<QObject*>(data), "stateChanged", Qt::QueuedConnection);
    Q_ASSERT(ret);

    return GST_BUS_PASS;
}
```

The problem is, `stateChanged` (doesn't matter whether it is a slot or signal) is not called. I've stepped into `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` with debugger, followed it till it called `PostMessage` (it is Qt 4.6.2 on Windows, by the way) – everything seemed to be OK.

Object pointed to by `data` lives in GUI thread, I've double-checked this.

How can I debug this problem? Or, better, maybe sidestep it altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0h my god.

I am *so* stupid.

I've spent literally *days* debugging this.

And the problem looked like this:

```
bool VideoWidget::event(QEvent* e)
{
    if (!impl_)
        return false;

    // ...
}
```

Yes, I've reimplemented `QObject::event()` (to add some special processing for show/hide and resize events), and *did not call the base method*. And, guess what, `Qt::QueuedConnection` uses `QEvent`s to make the deferred calls.

Never do things like I did. Really.

Or, dear Qt, can you please use [NVI](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) to guard us against this sort of mistakes?